# Telebot нет цикла

Tags: python, циклы, telebot, pycharm

*Доброго дня всем.
Изучаю создание ТГ ботов на Python.
Прошу строго не ругать и подсказать решение.
Код ниже:*

```
import telebot 

token = "здесь токен"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start','help']) 
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hi')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

на мой взгляд бот не зацикливается т.к. в терминале PyCharm выдаёт "Process finished with exit code 0"

Пробовал изменять bot.polling. Пробовал использовать прокси. Бот в ТГ не отвечает.

pyTelegramBotAPI   4.5.1

Заранее благодарю за советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.polling(none_stop=False,interval=1)
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось,
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Проблема явно с pycharm. Я запустил у себя ваш код с своей правкой - все отлично работает. Попробуйте в том же IDLE запустите и проверьте результат. Возможно вы копируете не правильный токен

Comment: спасибо за подсказку.
в IDLE стало работать и бот отвечает в ТГ.

Но нету ли идей, почему код не циклится в PyCharm?

Comment: Вы установили библиотеки через интерпретатор pycharm?

Comment: pyTelegramBotAPI   4.5.1
pip                22.1
virtualenv         20.14.1

Данные элементы (если Вы про них), устанавливал через Terminal PycHarm

Comment: Тогда если честно не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

По факту сделал следующее:
Код ниже работает.
Через Терминал PyCharm удалил библbотеку Telebot.
Попробовал её установить через cmd.
Почему-то она не подгрузилась в Pycharm. Поэтому в PyCharm повторил установку.
По итогу всё стало работать.

```
import telebot

token = ""

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start','help'])
def send_welcome(message):
bot.reply_to(message, 'Hi')

bot.polling()
```